# Duda sobre css o jquery Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estoy realizando un menú a pantalla completa.

Tengo un menú que, cuando hago *hover* sobre un enlace, muestro un texto descriptivo extra. El problema es que lo estoy haciendo por CSS y, cuando hago *hover*, me hace *hover* en todos los elementos del menú y me muestra todos los textos, en vez de solo en el que hago *hover*:

```css
.homepage-link{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 38px;
}

  .homepage-link .homepage-link-tagline {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%; }
  .homepage-link:hover .homepage-link-tagline {
 
    opacity: 1; }


.homepage-page-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0; }
  .touch .homepage-page-wrapper {
    display: none; }
  .touch .homepage.landing .homepage-page-wrapper {
    display: block; }

#homepage-page-overlay {
  
  opacity: 1;
/*  top: -100%;*/
  width: 100%;
/*  display: none;*/
  position: fixed; }
  #homepage-page-overlay .close-modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em; }
  .homepage #homepage-page-overlay {
    top: 0;
    display: block; }
    .homepage #homepage-page-overlay .close-modal {
      display: none; }
    .homepage #homepage-page-overlay .site-nav-search {
      display: none; }
```

```html
    <div id="homepage-page-overlay" class="page-wrapper homepage-page-wrapper">
        <div class="homepage-link">
                   <a href="inicio.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">INICIO</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">Mucho de nosotros</span>
                   <a href="empresa.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">EMPRESA</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Somos todos nosotros</span>
                   <a href="tienda.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">TIENDA</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Nuestros productos de tienda</span>
                   <a href="blog.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">BLOG</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Nuestras ideas mas listas</span>
                   <a href="contacto.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">CONTACTO</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Nuestra informacion</span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe si voy bien por CSS o si debería hacerlo mejor por jQuery?

Comment: Como comentario personal, de pocos años de experiencia. Utiliza CSS para los estilos visuales, o todo lo que se tenga que mostrar. Y con `jquery` trata de manejar las "interacciones" es decir, si hombre A, presiona Boton C,..  y cosas asi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, para solucionar este problema con que salgan todos los span al hacer hover solo debes encerrar la etiqueta "a" y la "span" dentro de un span o alguno similar.
y en el css reemplazar

".homepage-link:hover .homepage-link-tagline" por ".homepage-link span:hover .homepage-link-tagline".
Con esto (span:hover ) solo se activa el deseado.

```css
.homepage-link{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 38px;
}

  .homepage-link .homepage-link-tagline {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%; }
  .homepage-link span:hover .homepage-link-tagline {
 
    opacity: 1; }


.homepage-page-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0; }
  .touch .homepage-page-wrapper {
    display: none; }
  .touch .homepage.landing .homepage-page-wrapper {
    display: block; }

#homepage-page-overlay {
  
  opacity: 1;
/*  top: -100%;*/
  width: 100%;
/*  display: none;*/
  position: fixed; }
  #homepage-page-overlay .close-modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em; }
  .homepage #homepage-page-overlay {
    top: 0;
    display: block; }
    .homepage #homepage-page-overlay .close-modal {
      display: none; }
    .homepage #homepage-page-overlay .site-nav-search {
      display: none; }
```

```html
 <div id="homepage-page-overlay" class="page-wrapper homepage-page-wrapper">
        <div class="homepage-link">
          <span>       
   <a href="inicio.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">INICIO</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">Mucho de nosotros</span>
     </span>  
     <span>   
                   <a href="empresa.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">EMPRESA</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Somos todos nosotros</span>
       </span>  
     <span>  
                   <a href="tienda.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">TIENDA</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Nuestros productos de tienda</span>
       </span>  
     <span>  
                   <a href="blog.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">BLOG</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Nuestras ideas mas listas</span>
       </span>  
     <span>  
                   <a href="contacto.html" class="homepage-link homepage-link-ajax homepage-link--why-we-make">CONTACTO</a><span class="homepage-link-tagline">Nuestra informacion</span>
       </span>   

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto @FrankTorresRodriguez , mi duda es como podría implementar estos span a un menú de wordpress, ya que como sabemos wordpress viene con una estructura de menú definida. Gracias

Comment: Para esto debería usar la opción del gestor de menú que te permite añadir otros elementos como "Title Attribute".
Luego en el header.php modificas como se crea el menú y usas estos elementos.

Comment: Quiero mantener el menu de wordpress, este sería como un menu complementario que aparecería solo al acceder a la página

Comment: Igual puedes añadir en wordpress multiples menú en esa misma gestión, lo importante es modificar el php correspondiente a donde se va a visualizar el menú para cambiar la estructura y el css